# Python loop to divide x,y by two

Tags: python, loops

I have this simple blind game(blind game because we assume we don't know x and y values, we only know the difference between them is 10 and the starting point, we can't use other mathematical formulas like divide x by 10 or y by 5. We can only use 2(divide by 2), addition and subtraction just like in the code below.
Given x=100,y=110(works fine but if x=200 and y=210 or x=80 and y=90, doesn't work):

1. Divide x by 2 and divide y by 2 to get 50 and 55  respectively i.e  x=50,y=55(since x and y must end with zero in order for x and y to be divisible by two or become mutiples of 10 and 2. Since 55 is not, we add 5 to make it 60), so we first check if x+5==y(50+5=55 which is equal to y, so x becomes original 50 and we add 5 to y to make it 60(x=50,y=60). We divide x and y by 2 again to get x=25,y=30(we check if x+5=y or y-5=x i.e 25+5=30 which is y, we keep y and subtract 5 from x to get 20 i.e 25-5=20, so x=20,y=30). We divide x and y  by 2 again to get x=10,y=15, we keep on doing this steps until we get x=5,y=10

below are x and y values the way they should appear:

```
1. 100,110
2. 50,60
3. 20,30
4. 10,20
5. 5,10
```

And we break it further:

1. 100,110
2. 50,55(55+5=60, here 50+5 is equal to y(55), so we keep the original 50 and increment y(55) by 5 to 60).
3. 25,30(25-5=20, here x+5 is equal to y(30)  so we subtract 5 from x to get 20).
4. 10,15(15+5=20).
5. 5,10.

If we start with x as 200 and y as 210, it should look like this:

```
1. 200,210
2. 100,110
3. 50,60
4. 20,30
5. 10,20
6. 5,10
```

And we break it further:

```
1. 200,210
2. 100,105(105+5=110)
3. 50,55(55+5=60)
4. 25,30(25-5=20)
5. 10,15(15+5=20)
6. 5,10
```

The expected results(only multiples of 5):

```
x=100,y=110
start
100 110
50 55
25 30
10 15
5,10
(5, 10)
end
x=200,y=210
start
200 210
100 105
50 55
25 30
10 15
5,10
(5, 10)
end
```

Any help please?

Here is what i tried:

```py
def blind_game(x, y):

    while x>10:
        d=x
        print(x,y)

        if x + 5 == y:
            x = d
            y=y+5
            x=x/2
            y=y/2

        if y-5==x:
            y = y
            x=x-5

        x = x / 2
        y = y / 2

    return x, y

x = 100
y = 110

play = blind_game(x, y)
print(play)
```

Comment: Your description of the algorithm is a long run-on sentence. Can you add some periods?

Comment: `if x + 5 == y:` and `if y-5==x:` are equivalent -- remember your high school algebra.

Comment: `y = y` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Barmar i have edited and included periods, any help please? Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the rules of the game are as follows:

1. the difference between the two numbers is (and must remain) 10
2. each step, the numbers must be halved
3. if any number is odd before the division, you might add/subtract 5

Then the following code (you might need to edit it to print the initial values) should work (assuming `x < y`, `x, y` are even):

```py
def solve(x, y):
    while x > 10:
        x //= 2
        y //= 2

        if x % 2 == 1:
            x -= 5
        if y % 2 == 1:
            y += 5

        print(x, y)
```

The observation here is, that after the division by 2, the difference between the numbers becomes 5, so exactly one of them is odd, and to fix the rule (1), it suffices to either add 5 to the larger or subtract 5 from the smaller number.

---

To explain why your code is not working, there are multiple problems with it, including:

- (effectively) unused variables (`d`)
- float division instead of integer division
- possible double-division in case `x + 5 == y`

Comment: kindly modify your code to work without modulus operation on it(%2).

Comment: your code works like a charm, very nice. I accept this as the correct answer. **Thank you so very much brother**.

Comment: sorry, i wasn't here... wdym remove modulus? i believe it can't be solved then - how do you decide on which number of edit if you don't know its parity? @BrianHanison

Comment: it can be solved without modulus operation. I replaced the second modulus operation with if x+5==y and it still worked...i tried several workarounds and i realized a boolean operation of true and false can help or checking the difference between them especially the previous x against the current y and vice versa coz everytime we divide one will be odd and the other one will be even(ends with zero)

Comment: we can also add a third variable z(x=100,y=110 and z=90) to keep track of x and y...just thinking